# Strong Parameters in accepts_nested_attributes_for from multiple classes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters

It might look a long post but don't be afraid ;)
I'm having a bit of problems with my **create** function from my **conversation** controller. It's because for using the new Rails 4 with **strong parameters** from another models that in fact could be considered as a child. At the moment the code is working but I'm not sure if the use of the **strong parameters** it is used correctly. So let's take a look at the code:

Here is the **ConversationMessage** Model

```
class ConversationMessage < ActiveRecord::Base
      # def change
      #   create_table :conversation_messages do |t|
      #     t.integer :message_id
      #     t.integer :conversation_id
      #   end
      # end

  belongs_to :message, class_name: 'Message', foreign_key: :message_id

  belongs_to :conversation, class_name: 'Conversation', foreign_key: :conversation_id
end
```

Here is the **MessageGroupMessage** Model

```
class MessageGroupMessage < ActiveRecord::Base
    # def change
    #   create_table :message_group_messages do |t|     
    #     t.integer :user_id
    #     t.integer :message_id
    #     t.integer :message_group_id
    #   end
    # end

    belongs_to :user, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: :user_id

    belongs_to :message, class_name: 'Message', foreign_key: :message_id

    belongs_to :message_group, class_name: 'MessageGroup', foreign_key: :message_group_id
end
```

Here is **MessageGroup** Model

```
class MessageGroup < ActiveRecord::Base
    # def change
    #   create_table :message_groups do |t|
    #     t.integer :id_user
    #     t.string :message_group_name
    #     t.timestamps
    #   end
    #   add_index :message_groups, :id_user
    # end

    belongs_to :user, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: :id_user

    has_and_belongs_to_many :messages, :join_table => "message_group_messages", class_name: "Message"

    has_many :message_group_messages, class_name: "MessageGroupMessage"
end
```

Here is **BodyMessage** Model

```
class BodyMessage < ActiveRecord::Base
    # def change
    #   create_table :body_messages do |t|
    #     t.integer :message_id
    #     t.text :body
    #     t.timestamps
    #   end
    #   add_index :body_messages, :message_id
    # end

    belongs_to :message, class_name: 'Message', foreign_key: :message_id
end
```

Here is **Message** Model

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
    # def change
    #   create_table :messages do |t|
    #     t.integer :id_sender
    #     t.integer :id_receiver
    #     t.timestamps
    #   end
    # end

    belongs_to :sender,     class_name: 'User', foreign_key: :id_sender
    belongs_to :receiver,   class_name: 'User', foreign_key: :id_receiver

    has_one :conversation_message, class_name: "ConversationMessage"

    has_one :conversation, through: :conversation_message, source: :conversation

    has_and_belongs_to_many :message_groups, :join_table => "message_group_messages", class_name: "MessageGroup"

    has_many :message_group_messages, class_name: "MessageGroupMessage"

    has_one :body_message, class_name: "BodyMessage"
end
```

Here is **FoldersConversation** Model

```
class FoldersConversation < ActiveRecord::Base
    # def change
    #   create_table :folders_conversations do |t|      
    #     t.integer :conversations_folder_id
    #     t.integer :conversation_id
    #   end
    # end

    belongs_to :conversation, class_name: 'Conversation', foreign_key: :conversation_id

    belongs_to :conversations_folder, class_name: 'ConversationsFolder', foreign_key: :conversations_folder_id
end
```

Here is **ConversationsFolder** Model

```
class ConversationsFolder < ActiveRecord::Base
    # def change
    #   create_table :conversations_folders do |t|
    #     t.integer :user_id
    #     t.string :folder_name
    #     t.timestamps
    #   end
    #   add_index :conversations_folders, :user_id
    # end

    belongs_to :user,   class_name: 'User', foreign_key: :user_id

    has_and_belongs_to_many :conversations, :join_table => "folders_conversations", class_name: "Conversation"

    has_many :folders_conversations, class_name: 'FoldersConversation'
end
```

Here is the **Conversation** Model, the one with will be the view that will become all the others classes as "*childs*"

```
class Conversation < ActiveRecord::Base
    # create_table :conversations do |t|        
    #   t.integer :sender_id
    #   t.integer :receiver_id
    #   t.string :subject
    #   t.timestamps
    # end

    belongs_to :sender, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: :sender_id
    belongs_to :receiver,   class_name: 'User', foreign_key: :receiver_id

    has_and_belongs_to_many :conversations_folders, :join_table => "folders_conversations", class_name: "ConversationsFolder"

    has_many :folders_conversations, class_name: 'FoldersConversation'

    has_many :message_group_messages, through: :messages, source: :message_group_messages

    has_many :message_groups, through: :messages, source: :message_groups

    has_and_belongs_to_many :messages, :join_table => "conversation_messages", class_name: "Message"
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :messages, allow_destroy: true

    has_many :body_messages, through: :messages, source: :body_message
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :body_messages, allow_destroy: true

    has_many :conversation_messages, class_name: "ConversationMessage"
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :conversation_messages, allow_destroy: true
end
```

Here is **Conversation** Controller

```
class ConversationsController < ApplicationController

    def create

        ### GET FROM VIEW -> HERE WHERE THE STRONG PARAMS SHOULD BE WORKING FOR: subject AND body
        @friend = User.friendly.find(params[:id_friend])
        @subject = params[:conversation][:conversation_attributes][:subject]
        @body = params[:conversation][:body_messages]

        @conversation_new = Conversation.new(conversation_params)
        @conversation = @conversation_new.create_new_conversation(current_user, @friend, @subject)

        @message_new = Message.new(message_params)
        @message = @message_new.message_new(current_user, @friend)

        @body_message_new = BodyMessage.new(body_message_params)
        @body_message = @body_message_new.body_message_new(@message, @body)

        @conversation_message_new = ConversationMessage.new(conversation_message_params)
        @conversation_message = @conversation_message_new.conversation_message_new(@conversation, @message)

        folders_conversation = @conversation.add_new_to_folders_conversation(current_user,@friend)

        respond_to do |format|
          format.html { redirect_to conversations_url }
          format.js
        end
    end

    private
        ###
        ### HERE ARE THE STRONG PARAMS
        ###

        def conversation_params
            params.require(:conversation).permit(:subject)
        end 

        ### THESE ARE THE ONES THAT ARE WORKING BUT FOR SURE NOT BY THE CORRECT WAY

        def message_params
            params.require(:conversation).permit(messages_attributes: [:id_receiver])
        end

        def body_message_params     
            params.require(:conversation).permit(body_messages_attributes: [:message_id, :body])
        end

        def conversation_message_params
            params.require(:conversation).permit(conversation_messages_attributes: [:message_id])
        end
    end
end
```

And all the info is sent to the controller by a **form_for**. Here is the **Create View** from **Conversation**

```
<%= form_for(@conversation, url: url_for(controller: 'conversations', action: 'create'), remote: true) do |f|  %>

    SELECT FRIEND
    <%= select_tag :id_friend, options_for_select(@friends.collect{|u| [u.name, u.name]}, {include_blank: 'Select Friend'} ) %>

    <%= f.fields_for :conversation_attributes do |s| %>

        <%= s.label :subject %>
        <%= s.text_field :subject %>                        
    <% end %>

    TITLE TEXT
    <%= f.text_area(:body_messages, cols: 20, rows: 20, value: "") %>

    <%= f.submit "Send", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
    <%= f.submit "Save in Draft", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

For sure is something that I can't see and it's making my head spins without finding why it's not working. If we find a solution it might also help many people having this same problem with **strong parameters** also

Answer (score 0):

This looks really complicated, I would start by simplifying it to dealing with 1 nested_attribute set to start

Your strong params will need to be built up something like this

```
def conversation_params
  message_attributes = {
    messages_attributes: [:id_receiver]
  }

  body_message_attributes = {
    body_messages_attributes: [:message_id, :body]
  }

  conversation_messages_attributes = {
    conversation_messages_attributes: [:message_id]
  }

  params.require(:conversation).permit(:subject
    message_attributes,
    body_message_attributes,
    conversation_messages_attributes
  )
end
```

Also, in your `forms_for @conversation` you don't need to put those under `fields_for` you would put the associated `has_many` objects under `fields_for`

```
<%= form_for(@conversation, url: url_for(controller: 'conversations', action: 'create'), remote: true) do |f|  %>

  <%= f.text_field :subject %>

  <%= f.fields_for :body_messages do |s| %>
    <%= s.text_area(:body, cols: 20, rows: 20, value: "") %>
  <% end %>

  # ...
```

Checkout the guides for more: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#building-complex-forms

Comment: Thanks for your answer, only today I could take a look at the code I trying to make this adjustments. Right now, at the line that I have **conversation = Conversation.new(conversation_params)** I get the error from the console: **TypeError (no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer):**. Are you sure that it's the best way when creating the object I should pass all the others params from the child class at the same time when it's not created yet?